# How to redirect a domain to a subdomain and keep URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

There used to be a Wordpress running under wp.mydomain.com  and a static presentation running under mydomain.com on my webhosting.

Now I want to change the satatic presentation to a Wordpress static page (eg. wp.mydomain.com/static-page) - when user enters mydomain.com, wp.mydomain.com/static-page should display, however the URL shouldn't change.

Currently I use in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://wp.mydomain.com/static-page
```

however it changes the URL. Is there a way to show static-page and keep the URL mydomain.com using .htacces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the right way to do. There were two problems in my approach -  I had to point relatively to the wordpress installation and I also need to change the order of my rewrite rules for subdomains. The correct rewrite rule, which has to be applied as the last one is this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ domains/wp.mydomain.com/index.php?page_id={page_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```